# Work around to uploading large folders onto Github

Tags: git, github

I am currently trying to upload my Laravel project into my GitHub account but I am running into the issue of not being able to upload the large vendor folder that "powers" the Laravel project.

Without this folder, anyone who forks my project would have to set up Laravel first which for the ease of my other developers I would like to avoid.

Is there some kind of workaround for this?

Comment: You could package laravel so it is trivial to install and distribute it separately?

Comment: *Large vendor folder what power Laravel project* should be use Composer for dependencies management, don't upload to Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

> Without this folder, anyone who forks my project would have to set up Laravel first which for the ease of my other developers I would like to avoid.

Yes, that should be an acceptable process, provided you can include in your repo a script or command which automates that process: the README would explicitly indicates anyone cloning the repo is supposed to execute said script/command.

As commented, a [`composer.json` and the `composer` command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) should help: a declarative approach (declaring the dependencies in `composer.json`) is better here than a vendoring approch (where you copy everything in a Git repo)